# Which Google API search module for Perl should I use?

Tags: perl, search

Which Google API search module for Perl do you recommend?

[REST::Google::Search](http://search.cpan.org/dist/REST-Google) or [Google::Search](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Google-Search)

Ease of use is important because I only really need to get the top two, maybe three results from the web search.

Also, is there a module that one knows of for getting things from wikipedia? Again easy of use is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be much to choose between them.

For what it's worth, I'd go with Google::Search, mostly because it's written using Moose under the hood :D